# with Angular UI Router, is it possible for the child state to call a function in the parent state's controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I can set values in the parent controller using stateParams -but want to call a function in that controller. Do I need to put something in the childs 'resolve:' or 'onEnter:' properties to call a function in the parents controller.  Note: the child states don't have any templates as they will use the parents template.

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('reports', {
        url: "/reports",
        templateUrl: "reports.parent.template.html",
        controller: "ReportsController",
        controllerAs: "reports"
    })
    .state('reports.users', {
        url: "/users",
        reportSettings: {
            title: "Active Users Report",
            reportName: "UserList.trdx"
        }
    })
    .state('reports.departments', {
        url: "/departments",
        reportSettings: {
            title: "Active Departments Report",
            reportName: "DepartmentList.trdx"
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: See this plunkr for solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/xnMDiv

Since you're injecting the ReportsController as 'reports', you can simply define the function within that controller as 'this.function' and then in the child view, use 'reports.function' to access it.

If you're want to call that function in the child controller (rather than the view HTML) then you'll need to create the function as a resolve at the parent and inject it into the child controller.

So:

```
resolve: { myfunction... }
```

and in your child controller

```
('myfunction')
```

Hopefully that makes sense. I'm mobile and writing is tricky.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  how would that look like in the code above ?

Comment: i've created a plunkr file to help explain what it is I am trying to do...   http://plnkr.co/edit/2qOLpbQrvLRQSB4BnjlU?p=info    -It could be that I  am going about this all wrong.

Comment: (i just been making some changes to it (basically trying to get it to work in plunkr)

Comment: please try this link instead   http://plnkr.co/edit/tBqm0K?p=preview   (not really used plunkr before -very cool though)

Comment: Wow   fantastic -thank you!    (it seems to ignore the first click though -do you have an idea on how it can pick it up?)

Comment: I'm not quite sure. It seems to not recognize the initial state change, or it's changing to 'reports' rather than 'reports.users'

Comment: Thanks again James -you got me 99% there  -If I figure out a fix then I will post an update here (so as to help the next person).

Comment: aha -fix it!  -controller look like this now...

var vm = this;
    vm.settings = $state.current.reportSettings;  
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){ 
      vm.settings = toState.reportSettings;
    });

here the new plunker link   http://plnkr.co/edit/xnMDiv

Comment: ah, good catch. Needed to define the settings variable so that it existed before the stateChangeStart event. thx for the follow up.